# relation between equallity of hermitian parts and numerical range

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Ok, so i am troubled with this question:

I need to prove that for some matrices 
$$ A \in C^{n\times n} , B \in C^{n\times n}$$
if the hermitian parts are equal $ A_H=0.5(A+A^*) = 0.5(B+B^*)=B_H $, the numerical range of **the original matrices** is equal. meaning:
$$ x^*Ax=x^*Bx \; \; \forall x $$

Although the question states that this is true (and i only need to prove it), i am really not sure why this is true - so an explanation will be welcome.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's not what "the numerical ranges are equal" means, and it's certainly not true.  Try e.g. $$A = \pmatrix{0 & i\cr i & 0\cr}, \ B = \pmatrix{0 & 0\cr 0 & 0\cr},\ x = \pmatrix{1\cr 1\cr}$$

Comment: i understand what you mean. the numerical range is the group {x*Mx for all nonzero x} and i cant compare each result on its own. also after losing the "it must be true feeling" a quick tryout showed that it is not true. thanks!

Comment: The numerical range is the set  of $x^\star M x$ for all $x$ with $x^\star x = 1$.  $x^\star A_H x$ is the real part of $x^\star A x$.  So what depends only on the Hermitian part is the projection of the numerical range on the real axis.